# HTTP2 Delay in pushed assets compared to non-pushed ones

Tags: http, http2, server-push

I'm implementing HTTP/2 push on my website. After having made it work, I'm bit surprised on the waterfall I get. I enabled throttling in Chrome to "Slow 3G" to see more accurately what is happening.

I'm pushing 4 assets (in that order):

1. home.min.css (12kB)
2. front_layout.css (213kB)
3. front_home.css (8kB)
4. front_layout.js (360kB)

Here is what I get during loading:
[image]
You can see that the 2 biggest files I'm pushing are "Pending". I can understand this, as even the main HTML document isn't finished loading yet. But the thing is that other non-pushed assets (the 2 images just below) are already loaded! How is it possible that a pushed asset hasn't started loading whereas non-pushed assets are finished loading?

Note that the blue part of a pushed asset is defined as "Reading Push", whereas the blue part of a old style request is defined as "Content Download". Could it be a plotting error from Chrome Inspector? Or a subtle difference between content download and reading push that I do not understand?

Let's see a bit later in the loading, it's even more surprising:
[image]
There is a strange delay between the end of the main HTML document and the start of one pushed asset. It seemed to me that a pushed asset would come right after the main response data, I don't get what this ~8 sec delay comes from. What do I miss?

At page load, here is what I get:
[image]

So:

1. Large pushed assets start downloading after other non-pushed assets
2. (last line) One large image (340kB, same as my large pushed asset) on another domain finished loading before my pushed assets (dispite being slower to download).

I get the same graph with Fast 3G. Only when I totally disable throttling (running on my own machine) I get what I expect:

[image]

I'm confused on what is going on. Is HTTP2 push a good thing in my case?

I read many articles on how http2 is working exactly but I really don't manage to understand what is happening in my case. Any insight is welcome!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like an implementation issue if you ask me. Are you running the latest version of your webserver and of Chrome? HTTP/2 being so new, there are unfortunately some implementation issues out there.

Comment: Did you ever find out the root cause to this? I'm seeing very similar behavior for a site I'm analyzing for speed on slower networks.

Comment: Unfortunately I did not manage to find an explanation on this. If you do I am still interested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that there is a mysterious gap between my index.html and the pushed resources. The end of the blue bar for the index.html is when the browser finishes downloading the file. Then it needs to parse the HTML, once it meets the point where it needs the pushed resource then it will start requesting for it. So I guess the gap is for the browser to parse the HTML and do some background stuff (eg. loading the HTML, allocating space...)

I'm not sure if this is the correct explanation but hope it could give you some insight (after all this time... or if you did find out the answer please share it! thx)